# How to conditionally remove specified number of elements from a set in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way to remove only one element(or more generally a specified number of elements) that fits certain criteria from a set.
for example, with the removeif function, it removes all instances that return true for a given condition, but what if I want to remove only one instance?
Here's my code:

```
fun evaluateGuess(secret: String, guess: String): Evaluation {
val map : HashMap<Char,HashSet<Int>> = hashMapOf('A' to HashSet<Int>(),
        'B' to HashSet<Int>(),'C' to HashSet<Int>(),
        'D' to HashSet<Int>(),'E' to HashSet<Int>(),'F' to HashSet<Int>())
    var rightPos = 0; var wrongPos =0;
 for(i in secret.indices){
      map.getValue(secret[i]).add(i)
 }
    for(i in guess.indices){
        if(map.getValue(guess[i]).isNotEmpty()){
            if(map.getValue(guess[i]).contains(i)){
                map.getValue(guess[i]).remove(i)
                rightPos++;
            }
             else{
                map.getValue(guess[i]).removeIf { it <i }//want to remove only ONE. 
                 wrongPos++
            }
        }
    }
    return Evaluation(rightPos,wrongPos);
}
```

Comment: how do you determine whicn instance you want to remove?

Comment: Might a filter be better than a removal?

Comment: @Bink yes and no. 
think about the removeFirst method. That's what I was looking for. By extension, if you want to remove the first, second, and third, you simply run a loop with the removeFirst method. Should probably put this as an independent answer to this question.

Comment: @Stachu if all instances meet the same criteria then it doesn't matter which one you remove: you just want to remove some, not all, if that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a standard function for that, whis is what I would do:

```
/**
 * removes up to [n] items fulfilling [condition] in place
 */
fun <T> MutableCollection<T>.removeAmountIfInPlace(n: Int, condition: (T)-> Boolean): MutableCollection<T>{
    repeat(n){
        firstOrNull(condition)?.let {remove(it)} ?: return this
    }
    return this
}

/**
 * Makes a copy of a Collection and returns that with up to n items fulfilling [condition] removed
 */
fun <T> Collection<T>.removeAmountIf(n: Int, condition: (T)-> Boolean): Collection<T> =
    toMutableList().removeAmountIfInPlace(n, condition)
```

Then, you can go `listOf(1,2,3,4,5).removeAmountIf(2){ it > 2}` which will give you `[1,2,5]`

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense, though after a little more digging around, I was able to find exactly what I was looking for in the kotlin docs. Specifically, retrieving by condition.
Here's the link: [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/collection-elements.html)
You can retrieve the first or last element that matches a given predicate using `map.first`